# When unit-testing my angularJS application with Jasmine, $interval is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

When writing unit tests for my application using Jasmine I have a $interval function which i need to test. To that extend, I am trying to inject $interval and call $interval.flush();

I have the following code (this is a stripped version)

```
describe("whatever", function () {

var $interval;

beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('whatever');

    angular.mock.inject(function (_$interval_) {
        $interval = _$interval_;
    });
});

describe("requestIntervalFunction", function () {
           $interval.flush(21000); //this gives me error "Cannot read property "flush" of undefined
        });
```

My question is, how come that it says $interval is undefined?

Comment: Instead of using `angular.mock`, try it with `angular` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your `specificaton` part.Thats why you getting such an error.

Add by define `it` function

```
describe("requestIntervalFunction", function() {
        it("test",function(){
            $interval.flush(21000); //this gives me error "Cannot read property "flush" of undefined    
        })

    });
```

Comment: Ahh, so it has to be inside an it-bracket - I will try this and report back! :) thanks!

Comment: That works and was totally my issue :) thanks a lot!